# How to correct a incorrect encoded string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, character-encoding

For instance, we need a third party lib to parse and get a file meta data. But the method will decode all the meta data via utf-8, even if the meta data is encoded in another encoding, it will return us a utf-8 encoded string. And the lib doesn't support any method to return a raw string data for us to encode it correctly. Now we know the file's original encoding of the meta data is, for example, GBK. Is there a way to correct the utf-8 encoded string to GBK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't, decoding something as UTF-8 that isn't in UTF-8 is lossy. That means, by the time you get the string from the lib, you have lost information and can't represent the original data as GBK. Change how the lib works, or change the file meta data to UTF-8.

Comment: Change the lib is somehow difficult. What if the file format and the lib are both closed sources?

Comment: @y.s. the file format and lib are closed source but incompatible with each other? File a bug report with the provider is your only option

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You should learn about ruby 1.9's `force_encoding` and `encode` methods on the string class.  I recommend converting everything to actually be UTF-8 as soon as possible before manipulating it in ruby.

Comment: The third party lib doesn't support any method to return a raw string data for us to encode it correctly.

Comment: I mean I don't have the chance to convert it into utf-8 as soon as possible, if I have to use this third party lib.